# Issues requesting a specific PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using PHP, AngularJS and HTML for a website. The website is to request data from the DB and display it on the website.

What I am trying to do is if I have lets say 3 functions in a PHP file and I have 3 controllers on a page I would like each controller to be able to request a specific function in the PHP file and return the results of the query.

Below is my code. I have test the queries and I know that they are working.

**HTML/AnguarJS**

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">text</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><b>Scoring Leaders</b></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table" ng-controller="leaders">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Points</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="table table-stripped">
                                    <tr ng-repeat="x in leaders">
                                        <td>{{ x.Num }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ x.Points}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><b>Goals Leaders</b></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            query here
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><b>Assists Leaders</b></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table" ng-controller="assists">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Points</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="table table-stripped">
                                    <tr ng-repeat="x in assists">
                                        <td>{{ x.Num }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ x.Points}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myStats', []);
        app.controller("leaders", function($scope, $http)
        {
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : './php/stats.php?action=getPlayerStats()',
            }).then(function mySuccess(response){
                $scope.leaders = response.data.records;
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.leaders = response.statusText;
            });
        });
        app.controller("assists", function($scope, $http){
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : './php/stats.php?action=getAssists()',
            }).then(function mySuccess(response){
                $scope.assists = response.data.records;
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.assists = response.statusText;
            });
        });
</script>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php
getPlayerStats();
getAssists();
function getPlayerStats()
{
    include_once("connect.php");

    $connect = connect();
    $seasonID = 21;

    $i = 1;
    $y = 0;
    $result = $connect->query("SELECT TP.TeamPlayerID, TP.Sweater, TP.Position, P.FirstName, P.LastName, 0 + TP.Sweater as SweaterNo
                                          , T.TeamID, T.TeamName
        from `tbl_Teams` T
        inner join `tbl_TeamPlayers` TP on (TP.TeamID=T.TeamID)
        inner join `tbl_Players` P on (P.PlayerID=TP.PlayerID)
        WHERE T.SeasonID=$seasonID
        order by SweaterNo, TP.TeamPlayerID  LIMIT 15");

    $output = "";

    while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if ($output != "") {$output .= ",";}
        $output .= '{"Num":"' . $i .'",';
        $output .= '"Name":"' . $rs["FirstName"] .' '.$rs["LastName"]. '",';
        $output .= '"Points":"' .$y .'"}';
        $i++;
    }
    $output ='{"records":['.$output.']}';
    error_log($output);
    $connect->close();
    echo($output);
}


function getAssists()
{
    include_once("connect.php");

    $connect = connect();

    $result = $connect->query("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM `tbl_Players`");

    $output = "";
    $i = 1;
    $y=0;
    while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($output != "") { $output .=",";}
        $output .= '{"Num":"' . $i .'",';
        $output .= '"Name":"' . $rs["FirstName"] .' '.$rs["LastName"]. '",';
        $output .= '"Points":"' .$y .'"}';
        $i++;
    }

    $output ='{"records":['.$output.']}';
    error_log($output);
    $connect->close();
    echo($output);
}
?>
```

I would like the Assists controller to be able to display the results from the `getAssists` function in the PHP file and the Leaders controller to display the results from the `getPlayerStats` function.

What am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, remove the parentheses in your URLs; it should be `action=getPlayerStats` and not `action=getPlayerStats()`

Now, don't call both functions in your PHP File:

```
// Incorrect way
getPlayerStats();
getAssists();
```

Instead, find out what's the action being requested:

```
// Correct way
$supported_actions = array('getPlayerStats', 'getAssists');
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : false;
if (!in_array($action, $supported_actions)) {
    // No valid action found, you might want to send a 404 status here, or something like that
}
$action(); // Execute the action!
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!! Am I correct in assuming as I add more functions to the PHP file they need to be added to the array fo $supported_actions?